# .NET Core Angular VS2017 Templates not building

Tags: angularjs

I created a new NetCore Angular project in VS 2017 using

```
dotnet new --install Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaTemplates::*
```

It was working fine until I made some changes like removing some existing components from template. There is only one home [component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xybH6.jpg) in the template.

After that, I run project without any change. I tried to clear cache and refresh the browser but unfortunately, I'm getting the same problem.

[Nothing change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vtfch.jpg)

Is there anything missing? The components I removed are still there. Why?

Comment: any errors in when compiling or error in console?

Comment: hi @GauravSrivastava: there is no error when build project and console..